# How to access the router UI when it's IP address says "the webpage is not available"? Its not just plug and play as in windows?

Tags: wireless, networking, router, wireless-access-point

I have some TPLink access points (and a travel router that can work as an access point), and want to configure them in order to extend my wifi signal.

**In windows I just plugged them into the computer and typed at the browser bar the ip address that the router or access point in question tells me so.** In example: 192.168.0.254. That address is the gate to the configuration steps. Its all just "plug-and-play" and I only have to know how to configure that router using the TPLink UI.

**Now with Ubuntu (14.04 LTS), I cannot even connect to that address.** When trying to connect to 192.168.0.254 it just tells me that "the webpage is not available".

I think I'm missing a silly step here...?

If I do ifconfig at the terminal, I get...

```
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f4:ec:38:9a:70:a8  
          inet addr:192.168.0.3  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::f6ec:38ff:fe9a:70a8/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:261849 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:178140 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:343648010 (343.6 MB)  TX bytes:23693413 (23.6 MB)
```

and

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c8:60:00:c0:bc:06  
          inet6 addr: fe80::ca60:ff:fec0:bc06/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:988 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1507 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:440009 (440.0 KB)  TX bytes:385185 (385.1 KB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f7400000-f7420000
```

Trying 192.168.0.3 won't get me "the webpage is not available"...

Comment: Do you have a manual IP in Ubuntu? Add the output of `ifconfig` command to your question.

Comment: Two possible issues: 1. How is your router connected to your computer? Try with an Ethernet cable. 2. Did you disable IPv4 in Network Manager at any time? It only shows an IPv6 address for eth0.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It is connected with an ethernet cable. Nope, I didn't disabled IPv4, nor change any config about the network. I am connected via wireless to though. Maybe I should disconnect myself? (it would be weird, but I haven't tried that now that I think of it).

Answer (score 0):

Open the system settings (search in dash) and then network. On the right you'll find a row that says Default route. Try using that ip and if it doesn't work add ":8080" to the ip (without the quotes)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it keeps saying that the webpage is not available. I've done a reset within the access point (with the tiny button that's in its back) in order to start anew, but now it won't connect at all to the device. In windows it does connect with their default ip (192.168.1.254)...